# How to use unicode in a rust macro argument?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, macro-rules

This is rougly what I want to use:

```rust
enum DashNumber<N> {
    NegInfinity,
    Number(N),
    Infinity,
}
macro_rules! dn {
    (-∞) => {
        DashNumber::NegInfinity
    };
    (∞) => {
        DashNumber::Infinity
    };
    ($e:expr) => {
        DashNumber::Number($e)
    };
}
```

however I get the following errors:

```
error: unknown start of token: \u{221e}
  --> src/main.rs:13:7
   |
13 |     (-∞) => {
   |       ^

error: unknown start of token: \u{221e}
  --> src/main.rs:16:6
   |
16 |     (∞) => {
   |      ^
```

What is wrong with this macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro arguments cannot be arbitrary text. They still have to be valid Rust tokens, and all types of brackets must be balanced; see [`MacroMatcher` here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html).

The `∞` character could only be possibly parsed as an identifier. However, identifiers [can only start with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html) characters from the [XID_Start](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AXID_Start%3A%5D&abb=on&g=&i=) Unicode set, which contains "letter-like" characters, or with `_`. Unfortunately, ∞ is not in that set, so it can't be used as a macro argument.

You'll have to use some alternate syntax, like quoting the symbol (`"∞"`) or using letters (`INF`).

Comment: it's also not in XID_Continue, unfortunately, I wish there could be extra characters as identifiers or make macromatcher also parse an extra fragment, for things like math operators and such. I've settled for `(-"∞"|-INF) => {DashNumber::NegInfinity};`

Comment: @Rainb Note that `-INF` is a valid expression, so this can cause confusion.